# Fragmentation and action bar sherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am using sherlock action bar API  for action bar implementation,My problem is 
I am using fragmentation in android.my main activity class is using more then 3
fragments to display things now I need to access that action bar in every fragment
but whenever I moved from main activity to any other fragments action bar is not 
accessible there. when ever I call any action it gives my null pointer exception kindly need your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that other fragments are extending `SherlockFragment`

And then call this method:

```
this.getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle(TheString);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ... further I have a question that in my custom action bar layout  I have an edit text in my action bar. Kindly tell me how to access the edit text. I tried different code but I didn't succeed.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchContact"
    android:hint="Search"/>
`

Here is some code of my custom action bar ...

Comment: can you explain further? Sorry for late reply!

Comment: I ma using fragmentation in my application I  have an actin bar which is initializing in the main activity action bar contain an edit text field which will work as a search view for every fragment.
Main activity is using fragmentation,it depend on user which fragment
he want to display on the main activity by selecting from menu.
every fragment have a list view, here is the scenario as u know I have
a search edit text field in the action bar and I want to access that 
edit text field in every fragment so that edit text value is access in the fragment and I can use that edit text value.

Comment: I have an idea, how about you type the method OnCreateOptionMenu in every fragment and also do not forget to write : setHasOptionsMenu(true) in OnCreateView 

Do this for every fragment and you can control the edittext in every fragment :)

Comment: Ok @kingOmar I ll do it then I ll let you know whether it ll work on not

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question, you need to reach the actionbar from the fragment inside an activity. So once you reach the activity from the fragment, from there you can get the  actionbar. say that you need to set the title:

from the fragment (it should be a SherlockFragment) do the following

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle(theTitle);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... further I have a question that in my custom action bar layout I have an edit text in my action bar. Kindly tell me how to access the edit text. I tried different code but I didn't succeed.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/searchContact" android:hint="Search"/>`
Here is some code of my custom action bar .. please note I want to access that edit text in my fragment

Comment: this should probably be a separate question, non a comment.
not tried but probably you simply need to call findviewbyid. 
I suppose a bit of googling and a couple of tests can help you.